# Form to search directory for .PHP files

Tags: php

I currently have this script that automatically searches my directory and displays the results in iframes within a div:

```
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $cur) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($filename);   
    if($file_info['extension'] === 'php') { 
        echo "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=0 src='$filename'></iframe>";
    }
}
?>
```

This works a treat, however if I want the user to actually use a 'search form' to search the directory for php files via key-words and display them in the same manner, how would I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You mean that user will search for files by their name or by their content ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! - search by their names only.

Comment: Thanks for constructive criticism Col. Shrapnel - I'm a newbie, I'm working in the dark and teaching myself. The PHP files in iframes works and for me and therefore 'at the moment' is good enough. Please don't post comments like this unless you suggest alternative  methods. It doesn't help anybody.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to index the files (content/filename/keywords entered) into a database. You can use that database to lookup the various filenames for the search terms and then rank them.

Comment: Would I set this up using PHPmyAdmin? If so any pointers/advice?

Comment: moreover, he has to store all his data into database instead of iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can create search form..

So user posts `search` param:

```
$search = strtolower($_POST['search']);
```

Then in your `foreach` do:

```
if ( strpos($search, strtolower($filename)) === false ) {
  continue;
}
```